# Perturbation of complex square root function

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, perturbation-theory

Let $z$ and $w$ be complex numbers.  Than it is claimed that
$$
|\sqrt{z+w} - \sqrt{z}| \leq \frac{|w|}{\sqrt{|z| + |w|}}
$$
or
$$
|\sqrt{z+w} + \sqrt{z}| \leq \frac{|w|}{\sqrt{|z| + |w|}}
$$
I am hoping someone can show me how to perform such a perturbation analysis in complex analysis.  I am able to prove this for real numbers via Taylor expansion.

Comment: You also have to specify which branch of the complex square root is chosen (there are two choices). If you are thinking of the “main branch” (which maps into the right half plane) then this looks wrong for $z = -1 -i\epsilon$, $z+w= -1 + i\epsilon$.

Comment: Yes, but the previous conjecture was false.  I'm adding the "or" condition here.

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed a typo.  The two inequalities differ by a "+"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This claim is absolutely wrong. Choose $w=-1,z=1$ therefore$$|\sqrt{z+w}-\sqrt z|=1\\|\sqrt{z+w}+\sqrt z|=1$$while $${|w|\over \sqrt{|w|+|z|}}={1\over\sqrt 2}$$but $$1\not\le {1\over \sqrt 2}$$

Comment: Oh wow, you're right.